# "try again later" when uploading to iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload a binary to iTunes Connect. I can upload, but when I click Save I'm told the changes can't be made and to try again later. But I've retried a few times, and other people aren't complaining. What's wrong?

Comment: This is not a programming-related question, it is an issue with Apple's iTunes Connect site.  I recommend asking on Apple's developer forums: http://devforums.apple.com/

Comment: I originally commented: when is the packaging structure for an application not a programming question?

But now I realize it's probably not obvious from the question that the problem is a packaging problems. Any idea how to make it clearer and still searchable?

Comment: Even so, how to compress and name your executable so that iTunes Connect accepts it is a problem with a specific website, not a code-related issue.  You could ask on Meta and see what everybody else thinks: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ , but that's my read on Stack Overflow's focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the file name of the zip you're trying to upload. A double extension like `MyCoolApplication.app.zip` seems to cause this. Instead, rename your upload to `MyCoolApplication.zip` or `MyCoolApplication-app.zip`.

Comment: Me too, actually. Funny. I wrote it and still managed to forget.